# How can I code a Linq query to do an upward Include?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 5 / SQL Server 2012 and I have the following classes:

```
public partial class Topic {
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubTopic> SubTopics { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubTopic {
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question {
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public virtual SubTopic SubTopic { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

I was using the following to get question details:

```
    public IList<Question> GetQuestionsUser(int userId, int questionStatusId) {
        var questions = _questionsRepository.GetAll()
            .Include(a => a.Answers)
            .ToList();
        return questions;
    }
```

Now I would like to also get the following two fields returned and also filter by SubjectId

- Topic.Name
- SubTopic.Name

I know I can Include down with Linq as I used this to get the Answers. However can I code my Linq query to get the Topic.Name, SubTopic.Name and filter by SubjectId?

Sorry if this sounds like I am asking for someone to do my work for me. However I would just like to get some ideas so once I know how to do it I can apply this to other similar needs that I have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 //assuming your repo GetAll() returns a DbQuery<T>
 var questions = _questionsRepository.GetAll()
                .Where(q=>q.SubTopic.Topic.SubjectId = mySubjectId)
                .Include(q=>q.Answers)
                .Include(q=>q.SubTopic.Topic)
                .ToList();
```